# Bukkit Permissions Not Being Enforced

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, server-administration, minecraft-bukkit

Ok so I have a Bukkit server up and running and I want to use the [Permissions Plugin](https://github.com/TheYeti/Permissions) to help give different users different permissions to help protect the server. I configured the permissions and reloaded them. However it seems that users have access to commands that they should not be able to run. Here is my set up...

**Groups.yml**

```
groups:
    Default:
        default: true
        info:
            build: false
        permissions:
    Builder:
        default: false
        info:
            build: true
        permissions:
            - 'worldedit.*'
            - 'mobSpawner.*'
            inheritance:
            - Default
    Moderator:
        default: false
        info:
            prefix: '&b'
            suffix: '&f'
            build: true
        inheritance:
            - Builder
        permissions:
            - 'worldedit.*'
            - 'motd.*'
            - 'worldguard.*'
    Admin:
        default: false
        info:
            prefix: '&4'
            suffix: '&f'
            build: true
        permissions:
            - '*'
```

**Users.yml**

```
users:
    test_user:
        groups:
        - Builder
        permissions:
    admin_user:
        permissions:
        groups:
        - Admin
```

When I run the `/pr test_user perms listall` command it outputs `worldedit.*, mobSpawner.*` which means that the permissions are being loaded correctly. But when I log on as test_user I am able to use the `/regions` command which is a part of WorldGuard plugin which the test_user should not have access to. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is your character name registered as an OP on the server? From my experience, OP status instantly gives permissions to all commands, even if the user isn't in a group that allows the '*' permission.

Comment: Along with what Kevin Y said, I've found that worlds that aren't called the default name (world) don't accept permissions until permissions are setup for a world called "world". YMMV.

Comment: @Kevin Y That was it! Thank you can you submit an answer so I can mark it as correct. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem may be that you are an OP on your server. I had this problem when setting up one a server – OPs seem to have permissions to access all commands (the `*` permission node), even if Essentials is trying to override it.